# SSRS report, issues with page size & footer and export to pdf

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, windows-error-reporting

I've checked the common problem with "body size = page size - margins" 
Body size :25,39159cm; 16,14342cm
[image]

Then i deploy template...
And the problem is still there - margins too big and still no sign of footer. where the problem could be?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a tablix? If it is dynamically adding columns, they will make the page width wider.

If you know how many columns you will end up with, remember to ensure the sum of the `static columns Width + (n*dynamic columns width) <= page width - (2*margin)`

Move the tablix to the far left edge. Shrink you columns (reduce font size if necessary) and make your margins smaller until you get your pages work as expected.

Similarly, as with rows on a table, you may not have allowed it to have a page break, so it grows too big. you will need to enable page breaks - but you could try to influence when they occur.

For the footer you need to have the margin large enough to see the content. At 0.1cm all you will see is the padding around the text!

Comment: Yes, i'm using tablix there. Page break is disabled, correct. So, i have to enable it, right? And what i have to do to fix wide? There's only fixed set of columns.

Comment: Well, it's become a bit better, but still no sign of footer. Added a screenshot to initial post.

Comment: Your footer size is 0.1 so it is being displayed but you are only seeing the padding not the content